# Adding a picture at the bottom of the mail content when sending e-mail with Python SMTP

Tags: python, email, outlook, smtp, email-attachments

Using the email and smtp libraries, I have developed a script that automatically sends mail via outlook's smtp server.

I enter the content of the mail and after the content is written I want to send the picture at the bottom.

But it sends the picture not at the bottom as I want it, but at the top of the mail content.

Example mail ( This is only image ) : https://ibb.co/d5HFwRG

My code:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

def send_mail(gender, messages, subject):
    global msg

    try:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        s = smtplib.SMTP(host="SMTP.office365.com", port=587)
        s.starttls()
        s.login(mail, password)

        msg['From'] = mail
        msg['To'] = example@outlook.com
        msg['Subject'] = messages

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain', 'utf-8'))

        attachment = open("image.jpg", "rb")
        p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        p.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(p)
        p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % image)
        msg.attach(p)

        s.send_message(msg)

        del msg

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

My code is actually much more complex, but I just showed you the function I use to send mail.
I had to change the names of some variables while adding them here, so the above code may not work for you, you need to edit it.

How can I get that picture sent in the Mail to the bottom?

Comment: I suspect you need to send an html email with the image embedded in the html to get this to work.  The python email docs include an example of how to do this.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes i know but is there a way to do this without using html?

Comment: Not  as far as I know (but I'm no expert) - if the image is just an attachment the client could display it anywhere, assuming it wants to display it at all.

Comment: okay thank you for support, i willl research it